# NO DATA FOUND oracle using cursor

Tags: oracle

I have been searching online using different solution suggestion to handle no data in this code but to no avail. how can I handle the exception if no data is found. How can I solve this problem. I am not an expert in oracle though!

```
    DECLARE

          nCheckOption   INT;
          no_data_found EXCEPTION;

          CURSOR TYPE_cursor IS
                         SELECT
                                                      D_NAL_REF.TRANS
                                                      , D_NAL_REF.INJ
                                                      , D_NAL_REF.REF
                         FROM  D_NAL_REF D_NAL_REF 
                         WHERE D_NAL_REF.REF IN
                                       (SELECT AG_REF.REF
                                       FROM   AG_REF A_REF
                                       WHERE A_REF.DESCEND_REF = 10
                                       );
BEGIN
          FOR rec IN TYPE_cursor
          LOOP

                         nCheckOption := 0;

                         SELECT 1
    INTO            nCheckOption
    FROM          PERSON_TYPE WHERE TRANS = rec.TRANS AND INJ = rec.INJ;

                         IF nCheckOption = 1 THEN

                                       UPDATE              PERSON_TYPE
                                       SET                      PERSON_TYPE.TYPE = rec.REF
                                       WHERE TRANS = rec.TRANS
                                       AND                     PERSON_TYPE.INJ = rec.INJ;



                         END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found
  THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Trapped the error!?');
          END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Alignment makes your code a little hard to read.  Does the select statement in your cursor return any data when you run it by itself?

Comment: yes. It returns data !

Comment: Do you get data, when you join with PERSON_TYPE?

Comment: Yes. There is data also but i am updating the person type with the NAL.REF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code to eliminate the inner SELECT, which is the only place in your code where I can see that a NO_DATA_FOUND exception could possibly be raised:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT d.TRANS,
                     d.INJ,
                     d.REF
                FROM D_NAL_REF d
                WHERE d.REF IN (SELECT a.REF
                                  FROM AG_REF a
                                  WHERE a.DESCEND_REF = 10) AND
                      (d.TRANS, d.INJ) IN (SELECT DISTINCT TRANS, INJ
                                             FROM PERSON_TYPE))
  LOOP
    UPDATE PERSON_TYPE
      SET TYPE = rec.REF
      WHERE TRANS = rec.TRANS AND
            INJ = rec.INJ;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Trapped the error!?');
END;
```

Comment: Tnanks. It is giving error encountered the symbol BEGIN when expecting one of the following ( select ( sql statemet )

Comment: You may need to add a `/` on a separate line at the end of the block. It works fine for me that way - [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ea7ba16f0b2267a9f3b6012ba9d8ed5)

Comment: thank you is working but it is now saying unique constraint violated even though there is no constrant violated if i upate it one by one

Comment: Clearly there's more in play here than is apparent. Please **edit your question** and provide complete descriptions of all tables involved, including all constraints and indexes, and provide sample data for all tables **as text** - do not post images of code or data. Then further assistance may be available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find if cursor contains any record or not. If cursor is empty then it must return that error message written in exception block.

Or you want to print error message if update statement do not find any record to update.

Here is the pseudo code.

```
Declare
  ncheckoption number := 0;
  Cursor type_cursor is ....
Begin

  For rec in type_cursor loop

    ncheckoption := ncheckoption + 1;

    Update ...

    If sql%rowcount = 0 then
      Dbms_output.put_line('error message, if you want here in case no record found in table to update');
      -- loop will continue
      -- if you want loop to break then issue exit statement here
    End if;

  End loop;

  If ncheckoption = 0 then
    Dbms_output.put_line('error message you want to print in case cursor is empty');
  End if;

End;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: it still  says no data found